# PHP: script to timeout server connection

Tags: php, apache, timeout, connection-timeout

I'm trying to test a server timeout case for the front end.

I have create PHP script

```
set_time_limit(20);

while ($i<=10)
{
     echo "i=$i ";
     sleep(100);
     $i++;
}
```

with a hope to get server connection time out for requesting that page but instead of that I have got 500 Internal Server error.

Any suggestion for a test server timeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, very simple with header();

```
<?php 

header("HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout");
exit;
```